# Calculator Mathematical Error

Tags: c#, math, unity-game-engine, stack, calculator

I am use [Dijkstra's Two-stack Calculator](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/13stacks/Evaluate.java.html) with Unity Engine.
I am get a mathematical error.

Input: *"3+2"*, Output: *5*

**BUT**

Input: *"30+20"*, Output: *2*

What wrong with this code ?

**CODE**

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class Calculator
{
    public float Evaluate(string Input)
    {
        string Expression = "(" + Input + ")";
        Stack<string> ops = new Stack<string>();
        Stack<float> vals = new Stack<float>();
        for (int i = 0; i < Expression.Length; i++)
        {
            string s = Expression.Substring(i, 1);
            if (s.Equals("(")) { }
            else if (s.Equals("+")) ops.Push(s);
            else if (s.Equals("-")) ops.Push(s);
            else if (s.Equals("*")) ops.Push(s);
            else if (s.Equals("/")) ops.Push(s);
            else if (s.Equals(")"))
            {
                int count = ops.Count;
                while (count > 0)
                {
                    string op = ops.Pop();
                    float v = vals.Pop();
                    if (op.Equals("+")) v = vals.Pop() + v;
                    else if (op.Equals("-")) v = vals.Pop() - v;
                    else if (op.Equals("*")) v = vals.Pop() * v;
                    else if (op.Equals("/")) v = vals.Pop() / v;
                    vals.Push(v);
                    count--;
                }
            }
            else vals.Push(float.Parse(s));
        }
        return vals.Pop();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you debugged it? At a glance, it doesn't account for values with two digits. It evaluates `2 + 0`. `3` and `0` are just left on the stack and never examined

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
else vals.Push(float.Parse(s));
```

This line only considers single digits at a time.

Run through your code:
 input = (30+20)

i=0
(
vals stack:
ops stack :

i=1
3
vals stack: 3
ops stack :

i=2
0
vals stack: 0, 3
ops stack :

i=3
+
vals stack: 0, 3
ops stack : +

i=4
2
vals stack: 2, 0, 3
ops stack : +

i=5
0
vals stack: 0, 2, 0, 3
ops stack : +

i=6
)
vals stack: **0, 2**, 0, 3
ops stack : +

When you finish, you pop the 0 and 2 and add them to get your final answer: 2